# how to restore Battery Optimization settings as optimized on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to achieve ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS on/off within the app. So in a specific activity, it should be on and other off.
I could achieve to request the permission and PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations() returning true when I check the app settings is also not optimized.
Now my question is; is there a way to restore this to back to Battery optimization programmatically without redirecting user to the App settings page. I couldnt find anything documented for this. There is also no specific flag for it.

Comment: nope, you cannot do that unless your App is device admin or you have root access

Comment: @Cheesebaron thats weird because you change eventually your own apps behavior not other app. you can remove from optimization but not put it back. Google make sometimes no sense.

Comment: It is a concious user interaction to add an App to ignore battery optimizations, this is for the most part not necessary for any App to have this setting, so Google is making it hard to change this option for Apps.